# How can I use Elasticlunr in Gatsby with page components?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I've a small Gatsby-Application and want to use the gatsby-plugin-elasticlunr-search to provide some basic search functionality to my side. Unfortunately all examples use MarkdownRemark to put content from markdown files into the Elasticlunr index, but I use for various reasons react components for each side.

Is there a way to graphql rendered pages in order to index them? 
If not, can I use gatsby-source-filesystem to index the source code of my pages (there is mostly HTML inside a file, but so far i could only retrieve metadata)?

My pages in the directory /src/pages look like this:

```js
export const IndexPage = (props) => (
  <Layout>
    <h1>This is my first page</h1>
  </Layout>
)
```

In my gatsby-config.js I tried to index the source code like this (which does not work - invalid config file):

```
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `pages`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/pages`,
      }
    },{
      resolve: `@gatsby-contrib/gatsby-plugin-elasticlunr-search`,
      options: {
        fields: [`name`, `body`],

        resolvers: {

          File: {
            name: node => node.name,
            body: node => node.internal.content // returns always null..
          }
        },
        filter: (node, getNode) => node.sourceInstanceName === `pages`
      },
```